# spring security - How can I modify the return object of @PostAuthorize in a custom SPEL method?

Tags: spring, spring-security, spring-3

I wish to filter a collection returned by a service method. This filtering would involve calling another service method and hence I am not going for `@PostFilter` as it calls the `SPEL` expression inside the annotation for each element of the collection. Instead, I am using `@PostAuthorize` as follows :

```
@PostAuthorize("canAssignToUser(returnObject)")
List<UserInfo> getUsers(int userId);
```

In the `canAssignToUser`, I am trying to remove users from the return list passed to it. Apparently, this is a problem, and there is some restriction on modifying the returned list. How can I modify the returned list from a method using method-level annotations and without the SPEL expression being called for each element of the list.

Answer (score 2):

The `@PostAuthorize` is used for evaluating a `boolean` value, so the interceptor does not pass the return value to the expression, (look [here](https://github.com/SpringSource/spring-security/blob/master/core/src/main/java/org/springframework/security/access/expression/method/ExpressionBasedPostInvocationAdvice.java#L28)).
What's your method of removing the elements without checking every element? (like the `@PostFilter` does)

I think you don't have a choice, if you want to use Spring Security for the filtering

Comment: Before calling evaluateAsBoolean for postAuthorize, it sets the return object into the expression handler.. We are actually able to get the entire collection in the custom SPEL expression.. the only problem being that we can't modify it. And, my problem is not that I parse each element before removing it, its that for checking each element, my custom SPEL method is being called.. I want my method to be called only once, with the entire collection delivered to it, which I can modify it... but u can't always get everything u want :)

Answer (score 0):

You can modify the returned object as you like. Even though the interceptor does not return the object you passed, it gets notified with the changes to the object. Eventually the returnedObject is modified. (Note: custom security method inside `@PostAuthorize` can only return boolean.)

```
public class CustomMethodSecurityExpressionRoot extends SecurityExpressionRoot implements MethodSecurityExpressionOperations {

    public CustomMethodSecurityExpressionRoot(Authentication authentication) {
        super(authentication);
    }

    public boolean canAssignToUser(Object returnObject) {
        // do modifications to returnObject
        return true;
    }
```

getUsers() method returns the modified list after evaluating`@PostAuthorize("canAssignToUser(returnObject)")` .